# geojson data not rendering with openlayers in geodjango

Tags: openlayers, geodjango, ajax

map.html javascript code

```
var map = new ol.Map({
        layers: [
          new ol.layer.Tile({
            source: new ol.source.OSM()
          })
        ],
        target: 'map',
        view: new ol.View({
          center: [0, 0],
          zoom: 2
        })
      });
      
       var vectorSourceJsonp  = new ol.source.Vector({
        format: new ol.format.GeoJSON(),
        loader: function(extent, resolution, projection) {
        
            
            $.ajax({
                        <!-- url: "{% url 'geojson_provinces' %}", -->
                        url:'/geojson_provinces/',
                        dataType: 'json',
                    });
                },
                strategy: ol.loadingstrategy.createTile(new ol.tilegrid.XYZ({
                    maxZoom: 19
                })),
                projection: 'EPSG:4326'
            });
             // Executed when data is loaded by the $.ajax method.
            var loadFeatures = function(response) {
                vectorSourceJsonp.addFeatures(vectorSourceJsonp.readFeatures(JSON.parse(response)));
            };
            // Vector layer
            var vectorLayerJsonp = new ol.layer.Vector({
                source: vectorSourceJsonp,
                projection : 'EPSG:4326',
                style: new ol.style.Style({
                    stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
                        color: 'green',
                        width: 2
                    })
                })
            });
            var mapJsonp = new ol.Map({
                target: 'mapJsonp',
                renderer: 'canvas',
                layers: [osmLayer, vectorLayerJsonp],
                view: new ol.View({
                    center: [-75.923853, 45.428736], 
                    maxZoom: 19,
                    zoom: 11
                })
            });
```

views.py

```
def geojson_provinces(request):
    conn = psycopg2.connect(dbname="geodjango",host='localhost',user='postgres', password='postgres', port=5433)
    dict_cur = conn.cursor(cursor_factory=psycopg2.extras.DictCursor)
    cur=conn.cursor()
    res = dict_cur.execute("SELECT ST_AsGeoJson(geom) AS json FROM pft_pft LIMIT 10;")

    points=dict_cur.fetchall()
    print (points)
    json_res  = []
    for row in points:
        json_obj  = row['json']
        print (json_obj)
        json_res.append(json_obj)
        print(json_res)
    #json = simplejson.dumps(data)
    
    dict_cur.close()
return render_to_response('map.html',
                          {'json_res': json.dumps(json_res)},
                         context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

urls.py

```
url(r'^geojson/$', geojson_provinces, name='geojson_provinces'),
```

only map is getting displayed . When I use the debugger in chrome this is what i get
[image]

and finally i get Uncaught TypeError: ol.tilegrid.XYZ is not a function
please help! I even tried changing the url to "{% url 'geojson_provinces' %}", but not working

Answer (score 2):

In v3.6.0 constructor:

```
new ol.tilegrid.XYZ(...)
```

has been replace by static function:

```
ol.tilegrid.createXYZ(...)
```

See ol3 [upgrade notes](https://github.com/openlayers/ol3/blob/master/changelog/upgrade-notes.md).